# How to merge 2 class element together?

Tags: javascript

I am practicing class in JavaScript . I want to create 2 users , each with a weapon , then a function inside the class to attack each players and reduce their health with their respective weapon damage . I'm trying to do it in 3 different files , all I'm trying to do is merge my User class with my Gun class , to attribute a weapon to my user .  But I have no idea how to do it.. I want something like that :

```
let John = new User("John", "Sniper);
let Michael = new User("Michael", "Shotgun");

John.attack("Michael");
```

Then I wanna have fun creating additional function in my class , but first I need to figure  out how to add a weapon to a user in my User class :)

I would like to provide what I've tried but I can't figure out any way to do it ..

**main.js**

```
import Gun from '/js/gun.js';
import User from '/js/user.js';

let players = [ new User("Mic", "sniper"), new User("AI", "rifle") ];

players[0].shootAt(players[1]);
players[1].shootAt(players[0]);
```

**user.js**

```
export default class User{
    constructor(userName, Gun){
        this.name = userName;
        this.health = 50;
        console.log(this.name + ' was created with ' + this.health + ' health');
    }

    shootAt(target){
        target.health -= gun.damage;
    }
}
```

**gun.js**

```
export default class Gun{
    constructor(){
        this.sniper = {
            damage : 150,
            magazine : 7,
            fireRate : 1.5   
        }
        this.rifle = {
            damage : 25,
            magazine : 30,
            fireRate : .05
        }
    }

}
```

This is not working :

```
let players = [ new User("Mic", "sniper"), new User("AI", "rifle") ];

players[0].shootAt(players[1]);
players[1].shootAt(players[0]);
```

but this is the result I'm looking for.. Help please !

Comment: _"all I'm trying to do is merge my User class with my Gun class"_  I don't think you should do that. This sounds more like a composition pattern where your `User` _has a_ `Gun`. See https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php

Comment: Line is invalid: `let John = new User("John", "Sniper);`

Comment: Also, wouldn't each type of gun be its own class that extends Gun?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is because you're not actually creating a new `Gun` object with any properties you're just passing a string to your `User` class, and your properties aren't accessible from the gun class.

For the `Gun` class you need to make sure that items are accessible, and that you remember the gun type. You need to add something like a `gunType` property to `Gun` then in `User` you store their gun in a property as well.

Look at the code below I've added some basic getters for the `Gun` properties that use the `gunType` to retrieve the data for the current gun. This will fall down if you use a type that isn't supported, so you would need to extend that area or create gun types by extending the `Gun` class as Mr. Poliwhril suggests. Then I pass new `Gun` objects to the `User` object, and store them in the `gun` property for later use.

```js
class User{
    constructor(userName, Gun){
        this.name = userName;
        this.health = 50;
        this.gun = Gun;
        console.log(this.name + ' was created with ' + this.health + ' health');
    }

    shootAt(target){
        target.health -= this.gun.damage;
    }
}

class Gun{
    constructor( gunType ){
        this.sniper = {
            damage : 150,
            magazine : 7,
            fireRate : 1.5   
        }
        this.rifle = {
            damage : 25,
            magazine : 30,
            fireRate : .05
        }

        this.gunType = gunType;
    }

    get damage() {
        return this[ this.gunType ].damage;
    }
    get magazine() {
        return this[ this.gunType ].magazine;
    }
    get fireRate() {
        return this[ this.gunType ].fireRate;
    }

}


players = [ new User("Mic", new Gun( "sniper") ), new User("AI", new Gun( "rifle" ) ) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with defining the gun, then creating the various types. After you know what a gun does and how to create them, you can assign them to a user.

The following example includes a battle simulation between two players.

As an extension, you can factor in reloading time for each gun too.

```js
class Gun {
  constructor(damage, magazineSize, fireRate, ammo) {
    this.damage = damage;
    this.magazineSize = magazineSize;
    this.fireRate = fireRate;
    this.ammo = ammo;
    this.inMagazine = ammo > magazineSize ? magazineSize : ammo;
  }
  getDamageOverTime(rateInSeconds) {
    let multiplier = this.fireRate * rateInSeconds;
    let estimatedDamageMultiplier = Math.ceil(multiplier);
    let actualDamageMultiplier = 0;
    while (estimatedDamageMultiplier > 0 && this.inMagazine > 0) {
      actualDamageMultiplier++;
      estimatedDamageMultiplier--;
      this.inMagazine--;
    }
    return this.damage * actualDamageMultiplier;
  }
  reload() {
    while (this.inMagazine < this.magazineSize && this.ammo > 0) {
      this.inMagazine++;
      this.ammo--;
    }
  }
  isMagazineEmpty() {
    return this.inMagazine <= 0;
  }
  isOutOfAmmo() {
    return this.ammo <= 0; 
  }
}

class Sniper extends Gun {
  constructor(ammo) {
    super(120, 5, 1.5, ammo);
  }
}

class Shotgun extends Gun {
  constructor(ammo) {
    super(45, 30, 0.5, ammo);
  }
}

class User {
  constructor(userName, gun, health) {
    this.name = userName;
    this.gun = gun;
    this.health = health;
    console.log(`${this.name} was created with ${this.health} health.`);
  }
  shootAt(target, rate) {
    if (this.gun.isMagazineEmpty()) {
      console.log(`${this.name} is out of ammo!`);
      this.gun.reload();
    } else {
      let damage = this.gun.getDamageOverTime(rate);
      target.health -= damage;
      console.log(`${this.name} shot at ${target.name} for ${damage} damage.`);
    }
  }
  isAlive() {
    return this.health > 0;
  }
  toString() {
    return `{ name: ${this.name}, health: ${this.health}, ammo: ${this.gun.inMagazine} }`;
  }
}

const DEBUG = true;
let john = new User("John", new Sniper(10), 200);
let michael = new User("Michael", new Shotgun(90), 1200);
battleSim([john, michael], 1000);

function battleSim(players, updateRateMs) {
  let loopId = setInterval(function() {
    if (DEBUG) console.log(players.join('\n'));
    if (players.filter(p => p.isAlive()).length < 2) {
      clearInterval(loopId);
      console.log(`${players.filter(p => p.isAlive())[0].name} is victorious!`);
      return;
    }
    let shootsFirst = Math.round(Math.random());
    let shootsSecond = 1 - shootsFirst;
    if (players[shootsFirst].isAlive()) {
      players[shootsFirst].shootAt(players[shootsSecond], updateRateMs / 1000);
    }
    if (players[shootsSecond].isAlive()) {
      players[shootsSecond].shootAt(players[shootsFirst], updateRateMs / 1000);
    }
  }, updateRateMs);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Ohh I understand now ! Thank you very much it is clear for me now :)